# Random WSAECONNREFUSED on Windows Server 2012 / IIS 8.0

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012

At our hosting provider we have a server running Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8.0, via VMWare.
It hosts several web applications. In addition to that, FTP runs on port 21 on FileZilla Server.
Since August this year, seemingly at random, the server sometimes refuses the connection on port 80 and 443 (WSAECONNREFUSED). It does never refuse the connection on port 21.
To give an illustration of how random this is: It happened every day this week but it never happened the two weeks before that.
We can't find anything in the IIS logging. The only thing we can find is that when connecting through port 80 (or 443), even on the server itself on 127.0.0.1, it will usually work fine but sometimes WSAECONNREFUSED starts popping up right in between successful connections.
Both we and our hosting provider so far don't have a clue what is causing it, other than that it's suspicious that it's happening on the ports that IIS is using, but IIS or the Windows event log will never report anything.
Our hosting provider made a clone of this server on which we disabled most of the web applications. This clone exhibits the same behaviour, even at the same times.
A third server, which is entirely new (and runs Windows Server 2012 R2) does not show this behaviour. All three are on the same network.
After two months of searching we still haven't find anything. Any pointers are really appreciated, as these errors are a problem for both ourselves and our customers.